# Canon MF4820D suddenly shows a strange error

Tags: 16.04, printing, canon

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my machine, with a Canon MF4820D that was working perfectly well(print scan & copy) till day before yesterday. Today however it shows an error while printing : [image: See the 'status' shown in the figure] 
I have absolutely no clue a to what I can do now. I have tried rebooting the machine as well as printer, but it still does not work. The copy and scan functions are working fine.

Comment: Try deleting the printer and re-adding it.

Comment: @heynnema Thnaks for the suggestion. However this too does not solve the issue